# Change background and text color of the button at the same time

Tags: android, button, background, textcolor

I'd like to change my button background and its text color when it's pressed.

Please check my following project and give me your suggestions ...

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dynamicbutton;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    myLayout.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 30);
    Button[] btn = new Button[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        btn[i] = new Button(this);
        btn[i].setId(i);
        btn[i].setText("Dynamic Button" + i);
        btn[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        btn[i].setTextSize(15);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                         btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton_background);
            btn[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.blue_text_color));

                    }
        else{
            btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graybutton_background);
            btn[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.gray_text_color));

        }
        myLayout.addView(btn[i]);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and **activity_main.xml** (layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and **Drawables:**

**bluebutton_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/orangebutton"
        />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/orangebutton"
        />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bluebutton"/>

</selector>
```

**graybutton_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangebutton"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangebutton"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/graybutton"/>

</selector>
```

**gray_text_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#f4f4f4"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#242425"/>
    <item android:color="#f4f4f4"/>

</selector>
```

**blue_text_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#242425"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#242425"/>
    <item android:color="#242425"/>

</selector>
```

**Best Regards**

Comment: What was the issue your facing?

Comment: I can't change my button background and its textColor at the same time (When it's clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You can use onClickListener() method.

Try these steps :

1. Declare your button array as

   final Button[] btn = new Button[5];
2. Declare a final int j in the for loop

   final int j = i;
3. Place the below code after your if else part in the for loop

   btn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   ```
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               if(btn[j].getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == Color.parseColor("#242425")){
                   btn[j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.gray_text_color));
                   btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graybutton_background);
               } else {
                   btn[j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.blue_text_color));
                   btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton_background);
               }
           }
       });
   ```

**Final code will look like :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    myLayout.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 30);
    final Button[] btn = new Button[5];                                   // 1
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        final int j = i;                                                  // 2
        btn[i] = new Button(this);
        btn[i].setId(i);
        btn[i].setText("Dynamic Button" + i);
        btn[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        btn[i].setTextSize(15);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                         btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton_background);
            btn[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.blue_text_color));

                    }
        else{
            btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graybutton_background);
            btn[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.gray_text_color));

        }
        myLayout.addView(btn[i]);

    }

    btn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                     // 3

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(btn[j].getTextColors().getDefaultColor() == Color.parseColor("#242425")){
                    btn[j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.gray_text_color));
                    btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graybutton_background);
                } else {
                    btn[j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.blue_text_color));
                    btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton_background);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You should at least tell if it worked for you or not.

Comment: But it's not working !!!
When you declare j as final, it means that it can't change its value (we can't have j++ item)
So, if I use your codes into my loop, my buttons background will change after click (e.g. blue buttons change to gray and gray change to blue !!!)
Also, if I use your code out of my loop, it doesn't work; Because i and j are were declared into loop ...
Any suggestion ?!

Comment: @FarshadKazemi i am not getting what you are trying to do now.

Comment: also i have tried the code myself and it works. There is nothing in the code as j++, where are you using this (j++) in your code and why?

Answer (score 0):

I explained my mean in the picture.

[Dynamic_Button_Image](http://loverfootball.persiangig.com/Image/x.jpg)

I'm going to need my button **background_image** and **textColor** changes together.

I used from **selector** tag for my **background_image**.

Also, I used from **selector** tag for change **textColor** of my button, when it's pressed.

When I press my button, **background_image** changes, but **textColor** just give default

value of my **.xml** file (**blue_text_color.xml** or **gray_text_color.xml**)

Comment: Is this answer to your question?

Comment: @Libin, it's not answer to my question ...
I've just explained my mean clearly with picture ...
it hasn't been solving yet !!!